# Install pycharm Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pycharm

I recently had to wipe my computer and reinstall everything.  I remember being able to install pycharm (community edition) with a single `sudo apt-get install` command and that was all.  I can't find it? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

The ppa mystic-mirage/pycharm is unfortunately not updated anymore. Another solution is to use ubuntu-make:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

And then install pycharm by running

`umake ide pycharm`

Comment: Having installed it via Ubuntu Make, what's then the correct process to update it? Just `umake ide pycharm` again? Or remove it via `umake -r ide pycharm` first?

Answer (score 1):

From the following website [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/latest-pycharm-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/) I found these two ways to install pycharm for ubuntu 16.04

You have several options:

First option:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
```

Second option:line by line version

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install pycharm
```

If you want the community version...

```
sudo apt install pycharm-community
```

Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it in one command though.  I have it working now so I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I am curious as to what your solution was for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm no longer maintain the repo, there is a new one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:viktor-krivak/pycharm
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pycharm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just easily launch Ubuntu software app, type `pycharm` on the search bar and install it.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm is also available as a snap package. If you’re on Ubuntu 16.04 or later, you can install PyCharm from the command line.

Try this for professional version -for both Scientific and Web Python development. With HTML, JS, and SQL support.

```
sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
```

OR

Community verson - for pure Python development

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```